# How to create automatic text file from a list in R?

Tags: r

If I have list element containing multiple data frames, and I want to write them as individual text files on my disk by names NP1 , NP2, NP3, how can I do that?

I used the following,

```
lapply(lst1,write.table)
```

But this doesn't solve the issue. How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways.  One with a `for` loop and one with `mapply`

Set up a list of data frames:

```
lst1 <- list(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5]),
             data.frame(z = 6:10, w = LETTERS[1:5]))
```

Loop through the list with a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
    write.table(lst1[[i]], paste0("NP", i, ".txt"))
}
```

Check the result:

```
read.table("NP1.txt")
read.table("NP2.txt")
```

Using `mapply`:

```
nm <- paste0("NP", seq_along(lst1), ".txt")  ## create the file names
mapply(write.table, lst1, file = nm)         ## write the files
# [[1]]
# NULL
#
# [[2]]
# NULL
```

Note that if you don't want the `NULL` values that come as a printed result, you can wrap the call in `invisible`

```
invisible(mapply(write.table, lst1, file = nm))
```

Comment: I have one more doubt. I am doing an analysis. So, when I executed this command, a large number of files were made ( >200). Now, each of the dataframe in the list has some number of rows. Is there some way I can remove those dataframe from the list that have < 3 rows and then execute this command as usual?

Comment: Yes, try creating a new list with `dfList[!sapply(dfList, nrow) < 3]` then run the code