# Saving elements of a list as data.frames using R

Tags: r, list, save, lapply

How can I save each element of a list in a in a separate .RData file?

Consider the following example:

```
# Generating a list containing 3 matrices

set.seed(1)
mylist=list(M1=matrix(LETTERS[sample(1:26,9)],3),M2=matrix(LETTERS[sample(1:26,9)],3),M3=matrix(LETTERS[sample(1:26,9)],3))
mylist[1:2]

# $M1
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "G"  "U"  "W" 
# [2,] "J"  "E"  "M" 
# [3,] "N"  "S"  "L" 
# 
# $M2
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "B"  "P"  "J" 
# [2,] "F"  "I"  "N" 
# [3,] "E"  "Q"  "R" 

# Transforming the list of matrices into a list of data frames

mylistdf=lapply(mylist,function(x)as.data.frame(x))
```

My best try (does not work)

```
lapply(mylistdf,function(x)save(mylistdf[x],file=paste0(getwd(),names(mylistdf)[x],'.RData')))
```

Comment: Try with `lapply(names(mylistdf), ...`

Comment: `lapply(names(mylistdf),function(x)save(x,file=paste0(getwd(),names(mylistdf)[x],'.RData')))` does not give the expected result

Comment: akrun's suggestion assumed that you'd know how to modify the rest of the code to handle looping over the names. But really, if you're tying yourself in knots trying to squeeze this into one line with `lapply` why not just write a `for` loop?

Comment: I used `lapply(names(mylistdf), function(x) {x1 <- mylistdf[[x]];save(x1, file=paste0(getwd(),'/', x, '.RData'))})` and was able to save it

Comment: @akrun Your code works perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: Really, if you only need a side effect and no return value, write a `for` loop.

Comment: The displayed filenames are correct but when loading these objects in R, it turns out that they are all named `x1`, instead of `M1`, `M2`and `M3`. Do you know why? `lapply(list('M1.RData', 'M2.RData', 'M3.RData'), load, .GlobalEnv)` gives `# [[1]]
# [1] "x1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "x1"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "x1"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop using `names` of the list object and `save`

```
lapply(names(mylistdf), function(x) {
       x1 <- mylistdf[[x]]
       save(x1, file=paste0(getwd(),'/', x, '.RData'))
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
invisible(lapply(names(mylist), function(u) {
assign(u, mylist[[u]])
save(list = u, file = paste0(getwd(), "/", u, ".RData"))
}))
```

The use of `invisible` comes from [How to create automatic text file from a list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068156/how-to-create-automatic-text-file-from-a-list-in-r) and the rest of the answer comes from [loop through all files in a directory, read and save them in an object R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911604/loop-through-all-files-in-a-directory-read-and-save-them-in-an-object-r/27912952).

I have tested the above code and it works.

Comment: This solution is very interesting because it gives the "right" name to the object contained in the .Rdata file. *I.e* when you load the .Rdata, it creates an R object with the actual name from mylist and not `u` or whatever variable name has been used in the custom function. In other words, you create an object named `X`, you save it in a file named `X.Rdata` and when you `load(X.Rdata)` you get an object `X`! Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like :

```
save.image(get(paste0("mylistdf$M",X)),file=paste0(getwd(),names(mylistdf)[x],'.RData'))
```

into your `lapply` function ?

Answer (score 0):

More efficient way is to use `map` function from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(.x = names(mylistdf), .f = function(x){
  assign(x, mylistdf[[x]])
  save(list = x, file = paste0(x, ".RData"))
  }
  )
```

or

```
library(tidytable)
dt_map(.x = names(mylistdf), .f = function(x){
  assign(x, mylistdf[[x]])
  save(list = x, file = paste0(x, ".RData"))
  }
  )
```